# Recurring billing tells duplicate subscription for the same user but different products for authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

Please help me with the issue I m facing, I am using PHP to develop it. And the problem occurred when user inserts same credit card details along with same name but for different products it says duplicate subscription.

Comment: Without any code we can't help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A116) (emphasis mine):

> The ARB system checks a new subscription for duplicates, using these
>   fields:
>
> - subscription.article.merchantID
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.payment.creditCard.cardNumber
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.payment.eCheck.routingNumber
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.payment.eCheck.accountNumber
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.customerID
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.billingInfo.billToAddress.firstName
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.billingInfo.billToAddress.lastName
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.billingInfo.billToAddress.company
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.billingInfo.billToAddress.streetAddress
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.billingInfo.billToAddress.city
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.billingInfo.billToAddress.stateProv
> - subscription.article.customerInfo.billingInfo.billToAddress.zip
> - subscription.orderInfo.amount subscription.orderInfo.invoice
> - subscription.recurrence.startDate subscription.recurrence.interval
> - subscription.recurrence.unit
>
> If all of these fields are duplicated in an existing subscription,
>   E00012 will result. **Modifying any of these fields should result in a
>   unique subscription.**